# Testing Strategy for Web Services based Android app

Tags: android, robolectric, android-testing, android-gradle-plugin

I have a web services based app i.e. each activity calls a particular web service and populate data into view. I haven't done any testing yet but I was in the process of switching to `Volley` and thought I might add some testing too.

I was wondering what testing strategies should be for such apps. I'm playing around with the [`gradle-android-test-plugin`](https://github.com/square/gradle-android-test-plugin) and although `Robolectric` doesn't play well with `Volley` yet, it should soon (I hope).

Anyways, so the structure I use for my app is this:

- `ObjectJacksonRequest` class which get the data from the webservices and parses them into POJOs
- `RequestQueue` standard volley request queue
- `BaseActivity` the parent activity of all my app's activities which houses the `RequestQueue` object and other common stuff
- Various Abstract activities which I use to separate the UI code from the network code. For example, the AbstractAppleActivity is extended by any activity that needs an apple. The abstract activity does things like check if the Apple is still in memory when returning, load new ones, set up adapters for list views, etc.

Here's the questions I currently have. I have some intuition on the answers should be but I'd like to hear from the community. I'm sure there are others questions too that people might have and we can add those to this list:

- What's a good way to test the `ObjectJacksonRequest` object for the various web services ? Should I be writing a separate test for each web service that returns and object ?
- Should I be testing network requests with the actual webservices or mock the responses ?
- Should I be testing the `BaseActivity` and the abstract activities or the activities that extend it for it's functionality ?
- What is the best way to test an activity that doesn't have any values inserted until the web request is completed ? For example, an activity that loads a list of apples.

Answer (score 1):

> - What's a good way to test the ObjectJacksonRequest object for the various web services ? Should I be writing a separate test for each
>     web service that returns and object ?

If I am understanding it correctly you want to test the webservice backend. In that case I would write a test per call, or even multiple tests per call one testing each response senario.

> - Should I be testing network requests with the actual webservices or mock the responses ?

I would mock out the responses. It is my experience that if you test against a real webservice, you will get random fails because the connection was to slow or timed out or something and you end up running your test twice just to be sure it wasn't a random fail.

> - Should I be testing the BaseActivity and the abstract activities or the activities that extend it for it's functionality ?

I would not test the BaseActivities unless they have a lot of logic.

> - What is the best way to test an activity that doesn't have any values inserted until the web request is completed ? For example, an
>     activity that loads a list of apples.

Mock out the webservice response, so that it has values. You can do this with Robolectric. I believe the relevant method is `Robolectric.addRequestInterceptor`

Answer (score 0):

I have more experience with testing now so here are my suggestions gathered for various sources:

```
- What's a good way to test the ObjectJacksonRequest object for the various web services ? 
- Should I be writing a separate test for each web service that returns an object ?
- Should I be testing the BaseActivity and the abstract activities or the activities that extend it for it's functionality ?
```

All of these questions can be bundled into one. This is the question of testing inheritance hierarchies. The answer is, unfortunately, it depends. In most cases however, for abstract classes, testing the sub-classes will test the parent classes as well. Unless you have methods that have different use cases in different sub-classes, in that case you might want to test the abstract class so you can test all the cases as you code them (although if this is happening, you might be better off defining more objects).

```
- Should I be testing network requests with the actual webservices or mock the responses ?
```

This is an easy one. Always mock. As the other answer mentioned, you run the risk of writing `flaky` tests if you are using real webservices. Not to mention that testing the webservices is not your responsibility. You should only be testing code that you are responsible for.

```
- What is the best way to test an activity that doesn't have any values inserted until the web request is completed ? For example, an activity that loads a list of apples
```

This should follow from the mocked service. Once you have the mocked service. You can use it to send data to the activity in a reliable way and test the outcome.

**Other Notes:**

While the above are specific answers. In general I've found it useful to make some engineering decisions that facilitate not only testing but modularity of your apps. So these are some of my tips and to-donts from the engineering mistakes I had in my app design as per the question.

- Use custom wrappers for services: In my question I am trying to move from Android's original HTTP to Volley. Part of the reason for these issues is that the app design couples the app with the networking library. One way to get around this is to use wrapper classes that are `injected` into your code. The underlying implementation of the wrapper class can then change without affecting the other source code. I have a blog post on this topic [here](http://saa.dfarooq.com/blog/2014/03/06/decoupling-network-from-app/).
- Use Java modules: The Android gradle plugin in based on the gradle java plugin. You can therefore create Java library modules in your Android app project. I have found this is the best way to `unit test` your code that doesn't interact with Android API's. This is way easier and faster than both the Android test framework and `Robolectric`. I find that when I'm using a Java library module, my UI code becomes lighter because I'm trying to have as much work done in the Java module as possible.